# Generate Spring Model Beans from XML beans configuration

Tags: java, spring

Is there any way like eclipse plugin or something to generate Spring beans java classes automatically from a XML beans configuration file.

Or any similar kind of way. As I am doing a new project setup for REST API/ Spring/ Hibernate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [spring boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) project [starters](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-starters). They can get you up and running quickly and there are many archetypes for common project requirements.